# OpenCV 3.2.0 linker error while building a project using cmake

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, linker-errors

I mistakenly removed my /usr/local folder after which I had to build OpenCV and Caffe again. Now my projects are not compiling. Each time I try to build the project using cmake there is an error the stops the progress.

```
[ 80%] Built target mygoturn
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/runTracker
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/runTracker.dir/src/visualizer/runTracker.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEi'
//usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/runTracker.dir/build.make:200: recipe for target '../bin/runTracker' failed
make[2]: *** [../bin/runTracker] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/runTracker.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/runTracker.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I checked with the command  pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv
 and got the following response given below:

```
-I/usr/include/opencv -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_video -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_viz -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_text -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

I am including then CMakeLists.txt file that contains the build sequence.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(mygoturn)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem regex REQUIRED)

# avoid "can not find -lopencv_dep_cudart"
set(CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME OFF)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
message("Open CV version is ${OpenCV_VERSION}")

set(Caffe_DIR ~/tracking/GOTURN/caffe)
find_package(Caffe REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${Caffe_DEFINITIONS})    # ex. -DCPU_ONLY
message("Caffe_DIR is ${Caffe_DIR}")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

add_library (${PROJECT_NAME}

        src/network/regressor.cpp
        src/network/regressor_base.cpp
        src/tracker/tracker.cpp
        src/helper/helper.cpp
        src/helper/bounding_box.cpp
        src/helper/image_proc.cpp

        src/network/regressor.h
        src/network/regressor_base.h
        src/tracker/tracker.h
        src/helper/helper.h
        src/helper/bounding_box.h
        src/helper/image_proc.h
       )

include_directories(src)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/visualizer/runTracker.cpp src/loader/loader_base.cpp src/loader/loader_base.h)
add_executable(runTracker ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Caffe_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries (runTracker ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Comment: Can you provide the full `g++` command you are using? If not, can you run `make VERBOSE=1` and verify that all your libraries are being provided in the link stage (e.g. `-lopencv_imgcodecs`)?

Answer (score 0):

After buidling the new version of the OpenCV library (opencv4), I found that there has been few implementation changes made to the highgui module, wherein few of the implementations present on the highgui module has been shifted to imgcodecs (mainly the imread and imwrite).

Setting the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS more specifically to include all the libraries or specifically the  -lopencv_imgcodecs would suffice.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lopencv_imgcodecs")
```

This happened to resolve the issue that I had been facing. The pkg-config --libs opencv lists all of the library modules that have been built in opencv4.